# Choose specific number with probability

Tags: r, random, numbers

How can one choose a number with a specific probability `p`?

Say we must choose between `{0, 1}` and the probability `p` stands for choosing `1`.

So when `p=0.8` we choose `1` with 80% and `0` with 20%.

Is there a simple solution in R for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at [`sample`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sample.html) function.

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(c(0,1), size=10, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2,0.8))
 [1] 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

From the helpfile you can read:

> `sample` takes a sample of the specified size from the elements of `x` using either with or without replacement.

and the argument `prob` in `sample` acts as ...

> A vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled.